# How is 仕掛け used in this sentence?

Tags: words

I don't understand how 仕掛け is used in on the [second panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJNSb.jpg):

> 仕掛けはもう竿に付いてるから
>
> 針にエサつけて放りこみゃいい

My attempt at understanding this:

Because 仕掛け is already attached to the rod, (you just need to) attach the bait to the hook then cast.

I would think 仕掛け = gadget = hook, though 針 is used to refer to hook right afterward, so I'm a bit doubtful that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did check this link: https://tsurineta.69moons.com/method-horsemackere-ukiduri/

It seems that 仕掛け refers to everything but the fishing rod.